# Scraping HTML table to rectangular array using LINQ

Tags: c#, html, linq, scrape

I would like to scrape the column headers and rows of data for each column into a two-dimensional array.  The data looks like the following:

```html
    <div id="content">
<!-- start left col--><div id="LeftCol-wss">
<h1>Aircraft Names</h1>


<h3>Names by Type</h3>
  <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="data">
    <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <td valign="top" width="25%">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="data">               
            <tr class="datatop">
            <td width="100%">
              Fighter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td align="top" class="datatop" width="100%">
              <br/>              
              <a href="/page/mig-29.html" >MiG-29</a>
            <br/>
              <a href="/page/f-15.html" >F-15</a>
            <br/>
              <a href="/page/f-86.html" >F-86</a>
            <br/>
                <br>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" width="25%">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="data">               
            <tr class="datahead">
            <td width="100%">
              Bomber</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td align="top" class="datatop" width="100%">
              <br/>
              <a href="/page/b-52.html" >B-52</a>
            <br/>
              <a href="/page/b-1b.html" >B-1B</a>
            <br/>
                <br>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
</div>
```

The result I am looking for will be a two-dimensional array that looks like:

- Fighter   MiG-29
- Fighter   F-15
- Fighter   F-86
- Bomber    B-52
- Bomber    B-1B

I am using C# and would prefer to use LINQ, but at this point I'll take any suggestions.

Comment: What makes you think LINQ can parse HTML? They're unrelated technologies. There's LINQ to XML but this isn't X(HT)ML (for example, you've got an unclosed `<br>` tag).

Comment: Did you try to code it at all?  At least make an attempt.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse HTML in C#, the canonical answer is to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).